# Finding Powershell names for Excel features

Tags: excel, powershell, methods

I want to automate the Excel process of *Data → Import Text File → text import wizard*

How do I find the PowerShell name for these menus?

Here is my code. I want it to find .txt files in a folder (which have delimiters) and import them into separate Excel files.

#needs 2 or more files to work. rubbish.txt must be in folder with other files.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$path = "S:\DATA EXCHANGE\Testing" #where the original files are
$path2="S:\DATA EXCHANGE\Resurgent\fromSFG\test" #where you want the new files to go
 Set-Location $path

$a= Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -include *.txt #only finds the text files
$numOfFiles= $a.count


For ($n=$numOfFiles-1; $n -gt -1; $n--)
{$b=$a[$n].name ;


    $z=$path+"/"+$b #finds original file for import

        $wb = $excel.Workbooks.OpenText(   #the import
        $z, # file to open
        [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform]::xlWindows, 
         1, # start from row 1
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType]::xlDelimited,
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextQualifier]::xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,
         $false, # Consecutive Delimiter
        $true, # tab
         $false, # semicolon
         $true, # comma
         $false, # space
         $true,  # use other
         '|')


 $y= $b -replace ".txt.*" #gets filename without extension

 $y= $path2+"/"+$y #adds path to filename
 #$y= $y+".xlsx" #adds xlsx to filename

  if ($b -eq "rubbish.txt")  {$Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close()}


 $Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("$y")
 #$Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close()

}



#$Excel.Workbooks.Close()
#$Excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question, you are looking at a way to import a CSV file directly into Excel.

I use the `Open()` method of the $excel.workbooks object.

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$file = get-item "d:\scripts\test.csv"
$excel.Visible=$true
$excel.displayalerts = $False
$wb = $excel.workbooks.open($file)
```

If that doesn't work, I use files I rename the .CSV file to .TXT, and open them with `OpenText`

**UPDATED to use '|' as delimiter**

```
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.OpenText(
         "mycsv.txt", # file to open
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform]::xlWindows, 
         1, # start from row 1
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType]::xlDelimited,
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextQualifier]::xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,
         $false, # Consecutive Delimiter
         $false, # tab
         $false, # semicolon
         $false, # comma
         $false, # space
         $true,  # use other
         '|')
```

Don't use `OpenText` with .CSV files directly, rename them first. Excel seems to work with CSV named files differently.

Comment: Similar. Its not a csv, but a text file delimited by |s, which is not a standard option in the import.

Comment: You can add other delimiters, see the doc of OpenText here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.opentext%28v=office.11%29.aspx I just updated the code, but did not test it.

Comment: What am I doing wrong ? ($b holds the filename)

$excel.ActiveWorkbook.Opentext($b,,,,, $false, $false,$false,$false,$false, $true, "|", xlTextFormat,,,,,)

Comment: you need to use commas and not semicolons, I also would not use empty arguments.

Comment: what do I fill them with?

Comment: Try the example I updated in the answer or at least start with that.

Comment: I've ran into a problem. When I save it, it keeps the .txt extension even when I remove .txt from the filename string and when I force it to save as an xlsx, it doesn't open in excel; it says the file is corrupt.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you are using?

Comment: i've updated the code. I think I understand the reason why its doing what its doing (except for the part that I need to have at least 2 files for the script to work !)

Answer (score 1):

Menu item names are there for the convenience of the user; labels you see there may or may not correspond directly to the COM methods you need to call. From any kind of a program (including a PowerShell script), you need to be interacting with the object model that the application exposes. Microsoft has Excel's documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7.aspx

That said, depending on how many files you're working with and what exactly you need to do with them, going this route may be very slow and tedious. In many cases, it may be faster to treat Excel as an ODBC data source and insert your data into spreadsheets as though they were databases.