# OpenText Hijacks the File Name in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

A user suggested using the OpenText command to import a pipe delimited text file into excel. The problem is, that this seems to hijack the filename and forces it to be a .txt instead of an xlsx. When I try to 
-replace ".txt.*", the .txt remains and when I try to force name the file .xlsx, it just makes a "corrupt" xlsx file that won't open properly in excel.

First Question
[Finding Powershell names for Excel features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491558/finding-powershell-names-for-excel-features/27492167?noredirect=1#comment43417001_27492167)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.txt` and `.xlsx` are fundamentally different file types. You can't magically convert one into the other by just renaming the file.

Going out on a limb I guess your problem is that you're trying to save the file, and `$excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($y)` (or whatever statement you use) doesn't create an actual workbook.

Try saving it as [`xlWorkbookDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx):

```
$excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($y, 51)
```

Comment: Ah. OpenText does not import text into a new file, it merely displays it in its old file.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Correct. `OpenText` does exactly what the name says: it opens a text file. Were it to import the file into something else the method probably would've been named `ImportText`.